# How to access sqlite3 tables generated by ruby on rails rvm install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm learning ruby on rails by reading the "agile web development with rails" book. I installed ruby and rails using rvm. I'm using the default sqlite3 database, and generating models and tables is awesome.

I'd like to manually browse my db, just to see the structure.

So at the command line is run

```
sqlite3
```

and in the shell

```
.tables
```

nothing shows up... Where are my tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to run

```
rails dbconsole
```

or

```
rails db
```

as it will load your database etc.

Comment: awesome! how do you guys answer so quickly?

Answer (score 0):

For added clarity, the reason ".tables" returned nothing is because you didn't load the database. Start sqlite3 this way:

sqlite3 pathToDatabase/databaseFileName